# Fully transparent ActionBarSherlock by using theme

Tags: android, dialog, transparent, actionbarsherlock

I am using [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) 4.0.2.

I need a fully transparent action bar (without the neon color bottom divider). Hence, I have the following style:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock">
    <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="icon">@drawable/ic_home</item>
    <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/ActionBarCompatTitle</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
</style>
```

By using above code, I will still have the following effect.

[image: SherlockFragmentActivity wit divider and with half-transparent background]

In order to disable the background, I put the following code in `SherlockFragmentActivity#onCreate`. Then the problem gone.

```
getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(null);
```

[image: SherlockFragmentActivity without divider and with transparent background]

However, I would like to see the solution being implemented in *styles.xml* instead of Java code, as I have many other devices with different screen configuration. I modified the *styles.xml* to the following, without using the previously mentioned fix in the Java code.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock">
    <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="icon">@drawable/ic_home</item>
    <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/ActionBarCompatTitle</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>

    <item name="android:background">@drawable/transparent</item>
    <item name="background">@drawable/transparent</item>
</style>
```

However, the neon divider still visible. It seems that my fix using `android:background` and `background` does not work. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 24):

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock">
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/AppTheme.ActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/AppTheme.ActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.ActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar">
    <item name="background">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

Comment: This answer should be accepted. It's a great option to present a debug menu !

Comment: hi, this creates a gray effect but not a transparent effect in android 2.3 , why could that be so? Please assist

Comment: Ok, got it, it works well on the device but not on the emulator. i hope thats the only reason.